# JS real time sliders?

Tags: javascript, function, slider

`<input type="range" id="slider">`
`document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener("change", function(){})`
this code waits until you let go of the slider to input a value. How can I make it so that if the function happens as the value changes, in real time?

---

[I want the box to chanmge as I move the slider [JS FIDDLE]](https://jsfiddle.net/nke7qbgw/)

Comment: You need to provide more details on the question, codes or even a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of listening to `change` events, listen to `input`:

```
document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener("input", function(){})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput

Comment: Thank you haha that's all I was looking for.